# SELECT from One Table an Element that Occurs Multiple Times in Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I need to find out the names of the students who have enrolled in *at least* two courses.

Creating the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
  StudentID varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  FirstName varchar(15),
  LastName varchar(30),
  Sex varchar(6),
  DOB date,
  Email varchar(40)
);

CREATE TABLE Enrols (
  StudentID varchar(20),
  CourseID varchar(20),
  CONSTRAINT Student_Course PRIMARY KEY (StudentID,CourseID),
  FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES Student(StudentID),
  FOREIGN KEY (CourseID) REFERENCES Course(CourseID)
);
```

My (unsuccessful) attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Student.FirstName,
  Student.LastName,
  Enrols.CourseID,                  
  COUNT (Student.FirstName) AS NumberOfNames
  FROM Student
  INNER JOIN Enrols
    ON Student.StudentID = Enrols.StudentID
  WHERE COUNT(Student.Firstname) >= 2;
```

Comment: In place of where you need to use `having` (with `group by` clause)

Comment: Ok thanks for the help

Comment: Why is studentid a VARCHAR?

Comment: @Strawberry to build upon what you're saying, why isn't `Sex` just one letter?  When querying, the order in which a `VARCHAR` is checked goes from left to right anyway (say row 123'456 has a `Sex` of `male`; `m` would be checked first, then `a` and so on).  Depending on the size of your table you might want to take every step possible to limit size.

Comment: Yeah the studentID contains letters and numbers so just used a varchar to keep things simple. Same with Sex/Gender I have to store it as the whole word "Male", "Female" its just what they want. But thank you for the help

Comment: @BremerSharp The student number that gets printed on the student card probably shouldn't be the same as the database internal id. There may be situations where you want to reconfigure student numbers. You wouldn't want to mess around with PRIMARY KEYs in order to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Student.FirstName AS "First Name",
  Student.LastName AS "Last Name",
  Enrols.CourseID AS "Course ID",
  COUNT(Student.FirstName) AS "Number of Names" 
  FROM Student
  INNER JOIN Enrols
    ON Student.StudentID = Enrols.StudentID  
  GROUP BY Student.FirstName
  HAVING COUNT(Student.FirstName) >= 2;
```

Will work but you will see only one `CourseId`. You do not need `DISTINCT`.

Comment: in place of `FirstName` you should use 'StudentID` as `FirstName` can be duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` (but not the curseID if you use group by)

```
SELECT Student.FirstName AS "First Name",
  Student.LastName AS "Last Name",          
  COUNT (*) AS "Number of Names"
  FROM Student
  INNER JOIN Enrols
    ON Student.StudentID = Enrols.StudentID
  HAVING COUNT(Student.Firstname) >= 2
  GROUP BY Student.FirstName, Student.LastName;
```

Comment: in group by clause don't use `ASC`.

Answer (score 0):

In place of `where` you can use combination of `group by` and `having` clause, like below -

```
SELECT Student.FirstName,
       Student.LastName,
       Student.StudentID,
       COUNT(CourseID) AS NumberOfCourceEnroll
  FROM Student
 INNER JOIN Enrols
    ON Student.StudentID = Enrols.StudentID
 group by Student.FirstName, Student.LastName, Student.StudentID
having COUNT(CourseID) >= 2;
```

you should be grouping by studentId as this is primary key in student master table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.*
           FROM student s
           JOIN enrols x
             ON x.studentid = s.studentid
           JOIN enrols y
             ON y.studentid = x.studentid
            AND y.courseid < x.courseid;
```